# How do you work around the inabilty to pass a list of cl_mem into a kernel invocation?

Tags: opencl

There are lots of real-world reasons you'd want to do this.  Ours is because we have a list of variable length data structures, and we want to be able to change the size of one of the elements without recopying them all.

Here's a few things I've tried:

1. Just have a lot of kernel arguments.  Sure, sounds hacky, but works for small N.  This is actually what we've been doing.
2. Do 1) with some sort of macro loop which extends the kernel args to the max size (which I think is device dependent).  I don't really want to do this... it sounds bad.
3. Create some sort of list of structs which contain pointers, and fill it before your kernel invocation.  I tried this, and I think it violates the spec.  According to what I've seen on the nVidia forums, preserving the address of a device pointer beyond one kernel invocation is illegal.  If anyone can point to where in the spec it says this, I'd love to know, because I can't find it.  However, this definitely breaks on ATI hardware, as it moves the objects around.
4. Give up, store the variable sized objects in a big array, and write a clever algorithm to use empty space so the whole array must be reflowed less often.  This will work, but is an inelegant, complicated design.  Also, it requires lots of scary pointer arithmetic...

Does anyone else have other ideas?  What about experiences trying to do this; is there a least hacky way? Why?

Answer (score 0):

To 3:
OpenCL 1.1 spec page 193 says "Arguments to kernel functions in a program cannot be declared as a pointer to a pointer(s)."

Struct containing a pointer to pointer (pointer to a buffer object) might not be against strict reading of this sentence but it's within the spirit: No pointers to buffer objects may be passed as arguments from host code to kernel even if they're hidden inside a user defined struct.

I'd opt for option 5: Do not use variable size data structures. If you have any way of making them constant size by all means do it. It will make your life a whole lot easier. To be precise there is no 'variable size structure'. Every struct definition produces constant sized structs, so if the size has changed then the struct itself has changed and therefore requires another mem object. Every pointer passed to kernel function must have a single type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sharpnelis answer option 5:

If the objects have similar size you could use unions on the biggest possible object size. But make sure you use explicit alignment. Pass a second buffer identifying the union used in each object in your variable-sized-objects-in-static-size-union buffer.

I reverted to this when using opencl lib code that only allowed one variable array of arbitrary type. I simply used `cl_float2` to pass two floats. Since the `cl_floatN` types are implemented as unions - what works for the build in types will work for you as well.